# CSS div coming inline

Tags: css, html, css-float

I am currently building a contact form. Code :

```
<div id="contact_form">
            <form action="contact.php" method="post">

                <div class="contact_fields">
                    <div class="cf1">NAME</div>
                    <div class="cf2">
                        <input type="text" name="name" />
                     </div>
                </div>

                <div class="contact_fields">     
                    <div class="cf1">EMAIL</div>
                    <div class="cf2">
                        <input type="text" name="name" />
                     </div>
                </div> 

                 <div class="contact_fields">     
                    <div class="cf1">PHONE</div>
                    <div class="cf2">
                        <input type="text" name="name" />
                     </div>
                </div> 

            </form>
        </div>
```

And The CSS :

```
#contact_form
{
    padding:12px 20px 10px 20px;
    background:#f5f5f5;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:700px;
}

.contact_fields
{
    width:580px;
    margin-top:20px;    
}

.cf1
{
    width:80px;
    float:left;
    color:#333333;
    font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}
.cf2
{
    width:280px;
    float:left;

}
.cf2 input
{
    height:25px;
    width:280px;
}
```

But the divs `contact_fields` are coming inline,instead of div with a break(see the image I have attached.)[image: contact form] Please offer me a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of your `float: left;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BV3vf/)

```
.cf2 {
    width:280px;
    float:left; <----Here
}
```

Comment: Thanks..its partially solved. Now the divs are not messed up but I want the name and text field in same line. If I remove `float:left` the text field is coming after name

Comment: @Nitish wait, I'll do that for you

Comment: @Nitish you don't even need extra div's, isn't this sufficient? cuts down your css and markup http://jsfiddle.net/BV3vf/4/

Answer (score 1):

Now define your parent `.contact_fields` `overflow:hidden;`

**As like this**

```
.contact_fields
{
overflow:hidden;    
}
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BV3vf/3/)***